# Show image after hover, not on click

Tags: javascript

I want to use my gallery to work in little different way.

Now I have

```
   <a href="/big-image.jpg" data-gallery="lightbox[gallery]">
      <img src="/small-image">
   </a>
```

It shows the gallery of different images (small images). If someone click on image, it shows big image in lightbox.

I need to improve it to show the image after hover it not on click. I can add ID or class to elements but I am stuck in how to do it with pure JS (can't use jQuery).

Thank you for show me the way or some tutorial.

Comment: Hi Patrik! Welcome to stackoverflow! Here are some helpful links that will guide you as you ask questions here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Basically, you are expected to show your code, and prove that you have put some effort into trying to get this to work. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. We help you figure out why the code you have already written isn't working like you want it to.

Comment: Well that depends largely on how your lightbox script works. It probably has some sort of API and a method to show an item, that you could call in your own mouseover handler. But I rather doubt that this is a good idea from the UX perspective to begin with; will depend on how your images are arranged, but unwanted effects by moving from one image in a grid to the next to fast or similar can easily be imagined. And after closing such a lightbox, I might need to make my way back to a certain image with my mouse cursor, which could also trigger unwanted images along the way … use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

i believe u want to use a modal, if so try this

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp
>   here instead of onclick event use onhover,
>   as

```
    $("#id_of_element").hover(function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with two approaches
1) remove image tag and set CSS property "`background-image: url("paper.gif")`" on anchor tag and same as change this property on hover 
2)

```
 document.getElementByTag("img").hover = function() {
document.getElementByTag("img")[0].src = "any url you want  " 
}
```

Comment: Well, I know this second way, but there is where I stuck. I have hundreds of images and I don't want to add hundreds of url's. Is possible to make it with src to img in <a> tag before but not to use specific URL?